# How to find a specific substring of text anywhere in my XML and select this text using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I need to find and select a specific substring of text using XPATH/XSLT (if possible) - in this case the entity code for a non-breaking space "&#xa0" then highlight this in my HTML output using some CSS.

I am not searching within a specific element node, I need to search from the root node of my document and find this entity wherever it appears. I do not know where this will appear in my XML, I just know the entity code I am looking for.

Here is a section of my document where "&#xa0" appears within the text:

```
<row rowsep="1">
<entry align="left" colname="col1" colsep="1">
<para>N/A&#xa0;=&#xa0;not applicable/not generally used, A&#xa0;=&#xa0;applicable </para>
</entry>
</row>
```

I'm using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @MF82

I've tried just using XPATH to search for the entity but it seems to be limited to only finding the element node or text node that contains it. 

So for example, I've tried for the entire XML "`/*[contains (.,'&#xa0;')`" and in the text node of a paragraph "`//para/text()[contains (.,'&#xa0;')]`".

I'm new to XPATH and XSLT so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: If it's just for debugging purposes you could use a [character map](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps) to replace the non-break-space character with a marker like "--NBSP--" wherever it appears.  This would include appearances within attribute values though, so you can't replace it with a CSS-able element using this technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 you could use `analyze-string` on all `text()` nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#160;">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <span class="highlight"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then need to set up other templates to transform the remaining elements to HTML where you include the CSS or link to some CSS document defining something like

`span.highlight { color: red; }`

The `span` or similar wrapper element is necessary in my view as CSS does not allow you to style a single letter or word within a text node.

Comment: Note: Instead of using `span.highlight { color: red; }` I used `span.highlight { background-color: red; }` as there was no text for the CSS to colour in the output.